# How can I fix any letter or overall character input in integer input

Tags: c, function, input, scanf, do-while

So basically I have a simple code where I'm working with square matrix, where either the matrix is generated randomly, or the user can input the numbers in matrix, but when I enter the size of it for example in this do-while:

```
 do {
                     printf("Define the size of the matrix: ");
                     scanf("%d", &n);
                         } while (n <= 1);
```

the cycle will just loop till I enter any number bigger than 1, but when I enter any letter, or character besides number, it gets stuck in infinite loop.

I have the same problem in my other function where the user inputs the number in matrix:

```
void input_matrix(double* matrix, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
        {
            printf("Define the value of %d. row a %d. column:\t", j+1 ,i+1);
            scanf("%lf", &matrix[i*n+j]);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to fix it, is there any easy way to fix my problem?

(sorry for my bad english, not a native speaker).

I tried looking on the internet for the answer, found it, but didn't know how to implement it in my code.

Comment: Usually read a line of input into a string with `fgets`, then use `sscanf` to get data from that string. If it fails, repeat. Unlike repeating use of `scanf`, `fgets` will read another line of input each time, so entering bad data won't get it it stuck forever like using `scanf` directly does.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't know how to use it, but ill try to find info about it, thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

You can check the response from `scanf("%d", &n);`, if it is less than 1, then it did not get an integer, so we need to remove it from the buffer.

i.e.

```
int n;
do {
   printf("Define the size of the matrix: ");

   int args = scanf("%d", &n);
   if (args < 1)
   {
      char dummy;
      scanf("%c", &dummy);  // eats a character off the buffer
      n = 0;
   }
} while (n <= 1);
```

Comment: Thank your for you answer, I tried it right away, it works just fine, but when I enter more then one letter, the code prints the sentence "Define the size of the matrix:" x times, x being the number of letters I typed

Comment: Oh your question didn't specify that more than one character/number would be entered at a time, otherwise I would have included that catch in the answer. I was just trying to show you how to handle a character input. Feel free to upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

I would normally use `fgets` to read a string, then try to convert the data into the string into the intended type. If that succeeds, great. Otherwise, repeat.

Unlike using `scanf` (and company) directly, this always reads data, so it doesn't get "stuck" in the input like using `scanf` directly can.

```cpp
int getInt(char const *prompt) { 
    static char buffer[1024];
    int retval;

    do {
        printf("%s", prompt);
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
    } while (scanf("%d", &retval) != 1);
    return retval;
}
```

This would be used something like this:

```cpp
int n = getInt("\nDefine the size of the matrix: ");
```

Demo entering bad data, and eventually usable data:

```
Define the size of the matrix: asdf

qwere

Define the size of the matrix: qwerpoiusadf

Define the size of the matrix: 1234

Size: 1234
```

The basic difference from using `scanf` directly is that this starts by reading a line of data into `buffer`. It doesn't pay any attention to what that data is really, just reads whatever characters you enter up to the next time you hit the <kbd>return</kbd>/<kbd>enter</kbd> key.

Then, after it's read that data in, it tries to convert it to an integer. But the important point is that regardless of whether that conversion succeeds or not, the data has all been read in from the system's input buffer into the `buffer` we provided. So the next time we call it, it will attempt to read another, new, line of data.

By contrast, when you use `scanf` directly, if you're trying to convert an integer, it "peeks" at the input, and if it's something like a letter that can't form part of an integer, it's simply left in the system's input buffer, so if you try to call `scanf` again, it'll attempt to process that same input again. If you try to convert it to an integer again, it'll fail again--and no matter how often you try to convert it to an integer, it'll continue to fail.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'll try to use it in my code, i don't really understand how, but i'll make it work somehow, thank you alot again

Comment: @SamuelGombárik: I've added some explanation about how/why this works (and why using `scanf` directly doesn't, unless you do something else with it to discard bad input).

Comment: Thank you alot for the explanation, it helped me understand it alot better. Thank you again, I think I will make it work now.